# How does this case class definition allow infix pattern matching?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class, infix-notation, parser-combinators

I recently wrote a parser using scala's [parser combinator library](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators). I decided I was curious about the implementation, and went digging.

While [reading through the code](https://github.com/scala/scala-parser-combinators/blob/v1.0.6/shared/src/main/scala/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala), I saw that `~` sequencing used a case class to hold the left and right values.

Attached is the following comment:

```
/** A wrapper over sequence of matches.
   *
   *  Given `p1: Parser[A]` and `p2: Parser[B]`, a parser composed with
   *  `p1 ~ p2` will have type `Parser[~[A, B]]`. The successful result
   *  of the parser can be extracted from this case class.
   *
   *  It also enables pattern matching, so something like this is possible:
   *
   *  {{{
   *  def concat(p1: Parser[String], p2: Parser[String]): Parser[String] =
   *    p1 ~ p2 ^^ { case a ~ b => a + b }
   *  }}}
   */
  case class ~[+a, +b](_1: a, _2: b) {
    override def toString = "("+ _1 +"~"+ _2 +")"
  }
```

Given that such code as mentioned is certainly possible, and that parsers defined using `a ~ b` can be extracted into values via `{ case a ~ b => ... }`, how exactly does this un-application work? I am aware of the `unapply` method in scala, but none is provided here. Do case classes provide one by default (I think yes)? If so, how does this particular case class become `case a ~ b` and not `case ~(a,b)`? Is this a pattern that can be exploited by scala programmers?

This differs from [objects with `unapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684754) in this question because no unapply method exists–or does it? Do case classes auto-magically receive unapply methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An object with unapply working in middle of a case statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684754/an-object-with-unapply-working-in-middle-of-a-case-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do case classes provide [`unapply`] by default (I think yes)?

Your suspicions are correct. `unapply()` is one of the many things automatically supplied in a case class. You can verify this for yourself by doing the following:

1. Write a simple `class` definition in its own file.
2. Compile the file only through the "typer" phase and save the results. (Invoke `scalac -Xshow-phases` to see a description of all the compiler phases.)
3. Edit the file. Add the word `case` before the class definition.
4. Repeat step 2.
5. Compare the two saved results.

From a Bash shell it might look like this.

```sh
%%> cat srcfile.scala
class XYZ(arg :Int)
%%> scalac -Xprint:4 srcfile.scala > plainClass.phase4
%%> vi srcfile.scala  # add “case” 
%%> scalac -Xprint:4 srcfile.scala > caseClass.phase4
%%> diff plainClass.phase4 caseClass.phase4
```

There will be a lot of compiler noise to wade through, but you'll see that by simply adding `case` to your class the compiler generates a ton of extra code.

Some of the things to note:

**`case class` instances**

- have `Product` and `Serializable` mixed in to the type
- provide public access to the constructor parameters
- have methods `copy()`, `productArity`, `productElement()`, and `canEqual()`.
- overrides (provides new code for) methods `productPrefix`, `productIterator`, `hashCode()`, `toString()`, and `equals()`

**the companion object** (created by the compiler)

- has methods `apply()` and `unapply()`
- overrides `toString()`

> If so, how does this particular case class become `case a ~ b` and not `case ~(a,b)`?

This turns out to be a nice (if rather obscure) convenience offered by the language.

The `unapply()` call returns a `Tuple` that can be patterned to infix notation. Again, this is pretty easy to verify.

```scala
class XX(val c:Char, val n:Int)
object XX {
  def unapply(arg: XX): Option[(Char, Int)] = Some((arg.c,arg.n))
}

val a XX b = new XX('g', 9)
//a: Char = g
//b: Int = 9
```